# Turn Bluetooth On & Off via Terminal

Tags: terminal, bluetooth, alias

I'm trying to find out how to turn Bluetooth On or Off by using the Terminal on macOS Catalina.

I used to be able to do it with the following commands:

```
alias bton="sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth ControllerPowerState -int 1"
alias btoff="sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth ControllerPowerState -int 0 && \sudo killall -HUP blued"
```

Unfortunately these no longer work.

Answer (score 5):

[Blueutil](https://github.com/toy/blueutil), a command-line utility for macOS that lets us turn Bluetooth on and off with one command!

Start by installing `blueutil` with `HomeBrew`:

```
brew install blueutil
```

The -p flag is a switch for turning Bluetooth on and off:

**Turn bluetooth off**

```
blueutil -p 0
```

**Turn bluetooth on**

```
blueutil -p 1
```

Comment: This is also the accepted answer on the potential duplicate.

Comment: is there no method of doing this without having to install a 3rd party app?